# How do I remove the number from an algorithm caption?

Tags: numbering, captions, algorithms

I want algorithm to NOT show the number in caption. How can i do that? Below is the code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\caption{ My Algorithm}
\IF
\ELSE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Please let me know.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

If this is for just one `algorithm` environment, you can locally redefine `\thealgorithm`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{}
\caption{A numberless algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE do something 
\end{algorithmic}
\addtocounter{algorithm}{-1}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want this to be the global behaviour, you can add

```
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{}
```

to the preamble.

Another option is to use the caption package and declare a new label format for algorithms, suppressing the numbering:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{numberless}{\ALG@name#1}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=numberless} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A numberless algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE do something 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]